# How to open a preview mode of a Seagate Crystal report?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

```
Process p = null;

if (p == null)
{
   p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\Report1.rpt";
   p.Start();
}
```

I am opening Seagate Crystal Reports with this code, this is showing the design view of Crystal Reports. But I want to open print preview mode. If anybody knows please help

Comment: Try setting `p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"`. If that doesn't work, then you may have to look to see if there is some interop that Crystal Reports provides that allows to open the file and show the print preview dialog.

Comment: this method Not working